# I dont remember my raspberry pi 3 manually set ip

Tags: ssh, dhcp, static-ip

Couple years back I had setup my raspi as a proxy (installed openssh on it etc..). I had connected it through ethernet cable to my router and I had manually set an IP so that when the pi restart it doesn't get a new IP.

Today (almost 2 years later) my router died and I'm trying to connect to the raspi but i don't remember what IP I had put .. I was fairly certain it was either 192.168.0.13 or 192.168.1.13 but I cannot ssh on it using neither or both so maybe it was something else.

I have tried

> sudo nmap -sS -p 22 -v 192.168.0.0/16

But it strangely doesn't seem to find anything open.

To fix the address Ip on the PI i remember I modified the the /etc/dhcpcd.conf with

```
nohook lookup-hostname
interface eth0

static ip_address={i dont remember}/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

Im pretty sure the raspi is not dead since I was able to connect to it (using the noIp dns) couple days ago.

What else can I try apart from nmap to try findout on what IP the the pi ?
Or is there any way I can ssh to it without knowing the ip?

Comment: If you have another GNU/Linux machine, you could simply read the configuration files after plugging in the MicroSD card into your card reader.

Comment: Does your new router use the same subnet?  For example, your new router may be using numbers like 10.0.0.0/16.  If you're not on the same subnet, then I don't think you can hit it via your router even if you remember the IP.

Comment: well I managed to enter on my PI by using a usb keyboard and a screen. i could then see in the file that the IP was 192.168.1.13. I still dont understand why I couldn't ssh into it when I connected it through ethernet cable to my computer. In my computer  card I had manuall set submash 255.255.255.0 and IP 192.168.1.10

Comment: Your original question was about accessing via your router. In order for that to work, the Raspberry Pi needs to have a setting consistent with the settings on your router. There's no reason to believe that your new router is configuring the same subnet settings as your old one. In fact, based on the IP that you have on your Raspberry Pi, I'd be that the new router is *not* configuring the same. In that case your router is blocking the traffic and it never reaches your Pi.